# Probability of N independent poissonian events in same time window?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, substitution, poisson-integrals

So the probability of two poisson events taking place against time can be given as:

$$P = r_1 r_2 \int_0^\inf dt_1 e^{-r_1t_1} \int_{t_1 - T}^{t_1 + T} dt_2 e^{-r_2t_2}$$

Where $$ X = t_1 - t_2 \quad -T < X < T$$

Are limits set by the fact these two events need to be T seconds from each other. I want to extrapolate this to N independent events, where there's now a probability of no events taking place. I've started with the equation

$$P(k) = nCc \cdot (\Pi_{0}^k r_ie^{-r_it_i})(\Pi_k^N e^{-r_iT}) = ABC$$

Where A is the binomial coefficient, B is the distribution above made for the k events which have succeeded, and C is for the (N-k) that have not. If each event has the same rate, this simplifies a little:

$$P(k) = nCc \cdot (\Pi_{0}^k re^{-rt_i})e^{-r(N - k)T}$$

And this is where I'm at. I know it's possible to use a substitution of a lot of substitutions like the first expression to solve this, but I'm not sure how to do this when *every event* is within the same time window. Does anyone have any advice? I'm also happy to approximate a little as long as the answer  would be close for high N

Comment: I should add that an approximation would probably be to just integrate between the limits T/2 and -T/2 or something to that effect, but that's probably missing a few vital details

Comment: possibly you want the $\exp(-rt)$ expressions to be inside the integrals?